# How to filter the Arraylist using pageable object?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data, java-stream

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    nameList.add("Harish");
    nameList.add("Ajith");
    nameList.add("Ramesh");
    nameList.add("Hari");
    nameList.add("Anto");
    nameList.add("john");
    nameList.add("bharath");
    nameList.add("kamal");
    nameList.add("Rajesh");

    System.out.println(nameList.size());
    Pageable pageable=  PageRequest.of(1,5);

}
```

I want to filter the name list based on the pageable object, 5 records per page. in case my case there is no jpa repository is involved.

Comment: `nameList.stream().limit(pageable.getPageSize()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

Option 1: Manually calculate the page size manually

```java
return nameList.subList(2, 4);
```

Option 2: Returns consecutive sublists of a list, each of the same size (the final list may be smaller)

Params:
list – the list to return consecutive sublists of
size – the desired size of each sublist (the last may be smaller)

```java
 Lists.partition(nameList, 5)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: i have used the sublist function to make this work